# Andorid sync code leads to internet access traffic

Tags: android, synchronization, traffic

I have a scheduled update method which sends a request to a URL every 30 seconds:

```
   public void repeatUpdate(){
       Timer t = new Timer();
       t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startUpdate();
            }
       },0,30000);
   }
```

and this is the update function:

```
 public void startUpdate(){
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        String url="http://www.example.com";
        String output  = getUrlContents(url);
        Log.i("text",output);
}
```

The example URL returns only 4 digits every time and is not a time consuming process. When I run this application I receive this message after a while as a system alert:

> Continuing Internet access will lead to traffic. Continue?

Does this error rise from this code? If *yes*, how should I optimize the schedule method? Is `timerTask()` a good method for scheduling updates?